# Why is Magento 2.3 supporting PHP 7.1 from 7.1.3 and excludes previous 7.1 versions?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Magento 2.3 system requirements says it supports PHP 7.1.3+, but this excludes 7.1.0, 7.1.1 and 7.1.2 versions:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Is it a mistake or is there any reason why the 3 previous minor versions are excluded?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd take the docs at their word unless you have a specific reason to think otherwise.

Comment: Well, I am asking because I need to specify the required versions of PHP for a module... and I can't understand why those 3 versions should be excluded...

Nullable types were introduced with PHP 7.1.0, nothing major changed after that, and I certainly can't find anything major with 7.1.3 that would explain why start from there..

Comment: Indeed package.json in vendor/magento/magento2-base uses: "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0". I'll follow that then, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Php7.1 has strict typing in it. Php 7.0 does not support that yet.